# Add minutes to an existing countdown timer

Tags: vb.net

how To add minutes to an existing countdown timer like while the timer is counting down I can add 10 mins with a push of a button so the time pluses like if the displayed time is 9.59 with the press of a button the time should display 19.59  and continue counting down

Public Class TIMER

```
Private alarmtime As Date
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If alarmtime < Date.Now Then
        Me.Timer1.Stop()
        MessageBox.Show("Time up")
    Else
        Dim remainingtime As TimeSpan = Me.alarmtime.Subtract(Date.Now)
        Me.Label1.Text = String.Format("{0}:{1:d2}:{2:d2}", _
        remainingtime.Hours, _
        remainingtime.Minutes, _
        remainingtime.Seconds)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        Me.alarmtime = Date.Now.AddHours(TextBox1.Text)
        Me.Timer1.Start()
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
        Me.alarmtime = Date.Now.AddMinutes(TextBox1.Text)
        Me.Timer1.Start()
    ElseIf RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
        Me.alarmtime = Date.Now.AddSeconds(TextBox1.Text)
        Me.Timer1.Start()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub GameTIMER_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

End Class

its just a basic countdown timer it works fine all I need for it to do is add minutes to it while its is counting down because when the timer is up I have to click the text box type in the number then press ok then the timer starts so instead off writhing in the textbox I just want to press a button and the countdown timer automatically adds lets say 10 minutes to current time being displayed while its counting down

Comment: Have you ever look `AddMinutes` method? Show your work first as well..

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a normal Timer, this should be your answer:

```
Me.Timer1.Interval += (60000 * 10)
```

**EDIT:**

Try stopping it first:

```
Me.Timer1.Stop()
Me.Timer1.Interval += (60000 * 10)
Me.Timer1.Start()
```

Comment: I can't seem to make the countdown timer add minutes to it while it's counting down I've looked as some addminutes methods they seem very complicated can any one plz assists me I don't know what code to use or where to implenet it into my existing code